# Application Pool Is Being Automatically Disabled

Tags: asp.net

I am stuck with an error from IIS6 application pool failure. I have generated a ASP.NET app that gets called as a sub HTML page containing dashboard items within. During the design of the app I have used threading for displaying dashboard faster by getting data from database much quicker. Since I placed the app into production once in a while I do get warnings in system event viewer that the process has terminated unexpectedly and that the process exit code was 0x0. Every weekend starting every Saturday around 8am it gets spammed with these warnings and then the actual application pools shuts off where then the website goes to unavailable mode.

I have checked also Application Event Viewer and noticed an error on the application side letting me know that application returned null reference for one of the functions within the app which is not possible.

Has anyone experienced similar issue or would know other things to test? 
Also, could there be a possibility that using threads within the app could cause these types of issues?

Thanks for your help.

Nick

Comment: What makes you a hundred percent shure that the null reference is not possible?

Comment: Well I guess nothing is 100% but due to not having any user input to the program so no errors could be caused by user passing parameters and this app gets called 100 times during the day for the same thing. The only thing I could think off is because this function goes against a database that connection gets lost and and database returns null... But when I run it through my PC and I run stress test I cannot duplicate the error.

Comment: Is there a maintenance window on Saturday around 8 that might explain a null output? What ever the cause may be, prepare your code to handle null values coming from the DB. Where ever you´re interfacing with another system, expect the worst and be prepared.

Comment: No Maintenance window, no backup during that period of time. I do have try catch blocks which if in case exception occurs within app to notify the team. Also User does not see the website outage during the warning which is also a little weird. Also I get no exceptions for database timeouts or connection failures. Its a random function sometime that fails and the threads call these function so I dont know if it would be a thread issue?